# I would like to display my output in an different line using ArrayList

Tags: java, file, arraylist

**Below is a way to read results from my file**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ReadObjects {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("Course.ser");
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

        ArrayList<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
        resultList = (ArrayList<Result>) ois.readObject();


        int size = 0;

        char[] results = new char[1000];



        try {
            File file = new File("Results.txt");
            FileReader reader = new FileReader(file);
            size = reader.read(results);
            System.out.println("Size = " + size );

            for(char c: results){
            System.out.print(c);
        }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




        ois.close();
        fis.close();
    }
}
```

**This is how my output looks like**

````
[< 101 | science | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: A >, < 102 | math | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: B+ >, < 103 | finance | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: A- >] ```
````

**How can i display my output as shown below using ARRAYLIST?What should be added to my code so that it will look like this?
**

```
< 101 | science | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: A >
< 102 | math | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: B+ >
< 103 | finance | Credit Hours: 3 | Grade: A- >
```

**Here are the details of my Result class............................. **

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class Result implements Serializable {
    private String courseCode;
    private String courseName;
    private String creditHours;
    private String grade;

    public Result(String courseCode, String courseName, String creditHours, String grade) {
        this.courseCode = courseCode;
        this.courseName = courseName;
        this.creditHours = creditHours;
        this.grade = grade;
    }


    public String toString(){
        return "< " + courseCode + " | " + courseName + " | " + "Credit Hours: " + creditHours + " | " + "Grade: " +grade + " >";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your problem via string split function. For that for output has to be generic. Currently I am seeing you are using **courseCode**, **courseName** without title and **Credit Hours**, **Grade** with title. My suggestion is make your output look like,

> courseCode | courseName | creditHours | grade

you can play with your data once you convert them into array.

1. First split string with ,
2. Then split substring with |

   ```
    String inpuString = "101 | science | 3 | A , 102 | math | 3 | B+ , 103 | finance | 3 | A- ";
   ArrayList<Result> resultList = new ArrayList<>();
   String[] resultArray = inpuString.split(",");


   for (int i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
       String[] item = resultArray[i].split("\\|");
       Result result = new Result(item[0].trim(), item[1].trim(), item[2].trim(), item[3].trim());
       resultList.add(result);
   }

   //Checking Result
   for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
       System.out.println(resultList.get(i).toString());
   }
   ```

Comment: But i need to read from the file                                     
`String inpuString = "101 | science | 3 | A , 102 | math | 3 | B+ , 103 | finance | 3 | A- "; `                                          This is should be read from the file

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_files_read.asp  here is a good tutorial for reading from file. save text in a variable and then split.